# Repeat UILocalNotification on certain days of week

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I want to  customize the repeat interval of a `UILocalNotification` to be on certain days of the week. I haven't found any information about this.

How can I program the repeat interval for notifications for certain days of the week, for example, repeat a notification on Sunday, Monday, and Friday?

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot set the `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification` to repeat only on particular days. You can set either repeat daily (every day), monthly (every month) or hourly (every hour). So the only feasible solution for your question is that if you want to set an alarm on Sunday, Monday and Tuesday then you have to set 3 alarms (one each for Sunday ,Monday and Tuesday) rather than one alarm.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to custom `repeatInterval` property. You have to setup each `UILocalNotification` on specify time. here is my codes.

```
    void (^insertAlarm)(NSDate*fire,NSString*sound,int alarmCount) = ^(NSDate*fire,NSString*sound,int alarmCount){
        UILocalNotification* notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.soundName = sound;
        notification.fireDate = fire;
        notification.repeatInterval = 0;
        notification.alertLaunchImage = IMG;
        notification.alertAction = ACTION_MSG;        
        notification.alertBody = BODY;
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        [notification release];
    };

    insertAlarm(date,sound.fileName,0);
    insertAlarm([date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60],sound.fileName,1);
```